# Complete migration guide for spotify

Tags: spotify

I'm looking for an complete migration guide for the new spotify app. I'm having a lot of event handlers for network change, app going to background and such. These are using constants like:

```
models.TOPLISTMATCHES.TRACKS
```

These are not included in the current API anymore. Is there any documentation on such details?

Answer (score 0):

Full documentation on the new API can be found [here](https://developer.spotify.com/docs/apps/api/1.0/) for the API, and [here](https://developer.spotify.com/docs/apps/views/1.0/) for the views framework.

Comment: There's no documentation on events like on/offline detection or the gallery pager replacement. There's a lot missing if you try to port an old app. E.g. the offline/online detection is mandatory to pass the Q/A tests. Btw: I know there's a api-tutorial app but that's full of slow bridged calls and old api usage. Would be really great if it would be updated to actual work smooth on a windows machine and uses stuff like the pager carousel.

Comment: On/offline properties and observing property changes is documented in the first link under the Session class. There's nothing called "Gallery pager" in the docs for the old API, so I'm not sure what its replacement might be.

Comment: i think it was called carousel. Displayed some items in a row and had a left and right button at the top.